# error: incompatible types AnyType topStuff = top.data;

Tags: linked-list, stack

I am writing a pop method using my old code from a previous lab about linkedlists. My code looks perfect, but I keep getting an error

> error: incompatible types
>   return top.data;
>   required: AnyType
>   found: Object
>   where AnyType is a type-variable:
>   AnyType extends Object decleared in class stack

I don't know how to get ride of this error! I've read other posts about this same error in other circumstances, but known seem to apply to my situation, or I don't know how to apply it to my situation.

```
public class Stack<AnyType> implements StackInter<AnyType>
{
    MyNode top = new MyNode();

    public void push(AnyType x)
    {
        MyNode newNode = new MyNode();
        newNode.data = top.data;
        top.data = x;
        newNode.next = top.next;
        top.next = newNode;
    }

    public AnyType pop()
    {
        if(isEmpty())
            return null;
        else{
            AnyType topStuf = top.data;   // Getting error on this line
            top = top.next;
            return topStuff;
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return top == null;
    }
    public AnyType(peek)
    {
        return top.data;
    }
}


public class MyNode<AnyType>
{
    public AnyType data;
    public MyNode<AnyType> next;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Anytype use T.
In Java generic type is defined as T by default as it extends Object Class.
And also peek function is not defined correctly.

```
public T peek() {
    //code here  
}
```

Comment: Should I change all AnyType declarations to T or just the method declarations?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I ended up casting top.data to type "T"

Comment: only T is used i think just refer to the javase docs for implementation details in generic programming.